# Django-Haystack: Understanding the use of data template in Haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am new to Haystack. I cannot understand why we have to use a template to render it with the text that we want to search. More simple , why we don't have to use something like this?

```
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, "and here the attributes to search")
```

**UPDATE**
To be more specific Let's say that we have an app `places` an here a model `countries`.
In the model i want to be searchable from haystack the fields `capital` and `biggest_cities`. So  in search_indexes.py i put

```
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True )
```

After make a template in the path search/indexes/places/countries_text.txt 
Here i put

```
{{ object.capital }}
{{ object.biggest_cites }}
```

Again the question is: why we have to use a template in order to accomplish our goal?

It wouldn't be easier to use something like

```
text = indexes.CharField(document=Truer, model_attr='capital',model_attr='biggest_cites')
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Could you show what you have, what you expect and what you'd like to do.

Comment: I made an example. Hope is better now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this Haystack Documentation page http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html ?

If you haven't, you must. If you have, read it again.

The SearchIndex API contains valuable fundamentals of how Haystack works on your project. It can also grant you a useful insight of "why you use templates to make your data searchable'.

> why we have to use a template in order to accomplish our goal?

From the Haystack Docs:

*"...we’re providing use_template=True on the text field. This allows us to use a data template (rather than error prone concatenation) to build the document the search engine will use in searching"*

As you can see, we can choose whether use a template or not.

Ps: sorry for the late post; I hope it helps you.